# What can go wrong if threads had to use process's stack?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

Why threads have their own stack? Why threads can't share process's stack along with all other resources? and most important what can go wrong if threads had to use process's stack?

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons, but the first and foremost is that (without optimization putting stuff in CPU registers), a function call's arguments, return value and return address are passed on the stack. So each thread therefore needs its own stack. The heap is of course common, and needs to be protected by e.g. using atomics or mutexes.